# Google analytics virtual page view vs regular page

Tags: google-analytics

I am sending a virtual page view(with a different name) in analytics on landing my default page if the user is not signed in.
The default page is itself getting logged in analytics as a regular page.

Is my virtual page affecting my regular page bounce rate?
If yes, how can I make it right?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to remember here. Firstly, Google Analytics cannot tell the difference between a virtual and a regular Page View. They are in fact the same thing, just triggered in different ways. They have the same impact on the Bounce Rate, and will appear in all reports in the same way.

Secondly, if you've triggered a virtual page view on a page, that won't automatically suppress the regular one. You could well be firing off a pair of page views (which really will kill your Bounce Rate).